# why do I get no such method exception

Tags: java, exception, casting

I have the following code :

```
    if (((FrameManager) FrameManager.getInstance()).hasPendingComponents()) {
        return false;
    }
```

this works fine for me but when I change the code for this:

```
FrameManager frameManager = (FrameManager) FrameManager.getInstance();
    if (frameManager.hasPendingComponents()) {
        return false;
    }
```

I get no such method exception at runtime, I did not understand why this is happening, can anyone help me and explain it for me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace and explain where and how you deploy this code and how you manage project dependencies.

Comment: the rhs here `FrameManager frameManager = (FrameManager) FrameManager.getInstance();` seems fishy, redundant casting atleast

Comment: I think it is not the problem.

Comment: @flashdisk, You seem to miss something here. Provide more info.

Comment: I have compiled again and it works perfectly, I have not done any change in the code